# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens COUNT IS CORRECT

Tags: php, pdo

I have been puzzling over this and trying to troubleshoot for hours. I have read maybe 30 questions on StackOverflow on this same error. None seem to pertain.
Field names and values are pulled from a long array. Previously, this was a MySQL query, that has worked well for the past 5 years, so nothing wrong with that array. As you can see, in troubleshooting, I added the variables $FCount, $VCount, and $PCount; to assure counts were the same, even though that's rather silly, as they are going to count as it goes through the loop, regardless. As a double-check, you can see in my exception code that I added the counts and strings as a second assurance, and counted them several times. I even exempted fields with blank values.
I am fairly new to PDO, and have no idea what is wrong here.

```
<?php
    $DSN = "mysql:host=$HOST;dbname=$DBName;charset=utf8";
    $Options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,);
    try{$pdo = new PDO($DSN, $USER, $PASSWORD, $Options);}
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        $LogData = "\n".date('Y-m-d H:i').' '.$_SESSION[PageName].' '.$e->getMessage().' '.(int)$e->getCode();
        error_log($LogData, 3, "error.log");
        exit('<h2 style="width:90%; border:2px solid #FF0000; padding:15px;">Server Connect Error! [1]</h2>');
    }
    $FCount = 0;
    $VCount = 0;
    $PCount = 0;
    foreach($RateVars as $key => $value)
    {
        if(!empty($value))
        {
            $FieldString .= trim($key) . ','; $FCount++;
            $VarString .= '"' . addslashes(trim($value)) . '",'; $VCount++;
            $PrepString .= '?, '; $PCount++;
        }
    }
    $FieldString    .= 'Server';
    $VarString      .= '"'.$Node.'"';
    $PrepString     .= '?';
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO Archive ('.$FieldString.') VALUES ('.$PrepString.')';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    try {$stmt->execute(array($VarString));}
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        $ErrorMsg = "DataBase Error in Save to Archive"; $Status=1;
        $LogData = "\n".date('Y-m-d H:i').' '.$_SESSION[PageName].' '.$ErrorMsg.' '.$e->getMessage().' '.(int)$e->getCode();
        $LogData .= "\n".'F: '.$FCount.' V: '.$VCount.' P: '.$PCount;
        $LogData .= "\n".'F: '.$FieldString."\n".' V: '.$VarString."\n".' P: '.$PrepString."\n".$sql;
        error_log($LogData, 3, "error.log");
    }

?>
```

Added note
Short example (there are 72 variables here) from my error log where I print out $sql:
INSERT INTO RateArchive (EstType,hszip,hczip,wswxds,etc...) VALUES ("W","58102","58652","000050000000000000","0500000000000000",etc.)
In answer to a comment below, the value of $Node is "DEV" and that is exactly how it comes out at the end of the value string.

Comment: You shouldn't put quotes around `$Node` if you're using it as a bound parameter. It will be escaped properly when inserting.

Comment: YOu also don't need `addslashes()` when using bound parameters.

Comment: On the one hand, it's true that you shouldn't have to escape values if you're using PDO... but that doesn't mean you can't get values that might screw up PDO's escaping itself. Why are you putting single and double quotes around each $VarString value? You don't need any of that if you're passing strings or numbers. Just push the raw data into $VarString and let PDO figure out what to do with it. ** EDIT ** sorry, $VarString should be an array you push those raw values into. That's the problem. It shouldn't be a string.

Comment: @Barmar Please see my added note just added at the end of the question. Also, I was wondering about the addslashed (left over from MySQL) Removing ...

Comment: @josjstrike $VarString is an array, I am simply defining the string, and inserting it into array(), no?

Comment: `$VarString` is not an array, it's a string. `array($VarString)` makes an array, but the array only has one element in it, not an element for each comma-separated item in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each parameter needs to be a separate element in the array passed to `$stmt->execute()`, it shouldn't be a single comma-separated string.

```
<?php
$DSN = "mysql:host=$HOST;dbname=$DBName;charset=utf8";
$Options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,);
try{$pdo = new PDO($DSN, $USER, $PASSWORD, $Options);}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $LogData = "\n".date('Y-m-d H:i').' '.$_SESSION[PageName].' '.$e->getMessage().' '.(int)$e->getCode();
    error_log($LogData, 3, "error.log");
    exit('<h2 style="width:90%; border:2px solid #FF0000; padding:15px;">Server Connect Error! [1]</h2>');
}
$FCount = 0;
$VCount = 0;
$PCount = 0;

$PrepString = str_repeat("?, ", count($RateVars));
$FieldString = implode(',', array_keys($RateVars));
$PrepString .= '?';
$FieldString .= ', Server';
$ValArray = array_values($RateVars);
$ValArray[] = $Node;
$sql = 'INSERT INTO Archive ('.$FieldString.') VALUES ('.$PrepString.')';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
try {
    $stmt->execute($ValArray);
} catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $ErrorMsg = "DataBase Error in Save to Archive"; $Status=1;
    $LogData = "\n".date('Y-m-d H:i').' '.$_SESSION[PageName].' '.$ErrorMsg.' '.$e->getMessage().' '.(int)$e->getCode();
    $LogData .= "\n".'F: '.$FCount.' V: '.$VCount.' P: '.$PCount;
    $LogData .= "\n".'F: '.$FieldString."\n".' V: '.implode(',', $ValArray)."\n".' P: '.$PrepString."\n".$sql;
    error_log($LogData, 3, "error.log");
}

?>
```

Comment: array_keys; array_values Didn't know or didn't remember those existed. Very useful :)